# how to keep mouse button pressed and move divs by greater speed

Tags: jquery

I have over 400 simple divs and two buttons to move them up and down. Everythig works but I want to keep mouse button pressed and move the items by much greater speed then using single click, one by one. Is it possible?

```js
$(document).on('click', '.item', function() {
  $('.marked').removeClass('marked');
  $(this).addClass('marked');
});

$('#mpup').click(function() {
  if ($('.marked').index() == 0) {
    return false;
  }
  var i = $('.marked').index() - 1;
  $('.marked').insertBefore($('.item').eq(i));
});

$('#mpdown').click(function() {
  var i = $('.marked').index() + 1;
  $('.marked').insertAfter($('.item').eq(i));
});
```

```css
.marked {
  background: red;
}
.item {
  cursor: pointer
}
.mpbtn {
  background: teal;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='itemwrap'>
  <div class='item marked'>323</div>
  <div class='item'>525</div>
  <div class='item'>727</div>
</div><br><br>
<div class='mpbtn' id='mpup'>UP</div><br>
<div class='mpbtn' id='mpdown'>DOWN</div>
```

Comment: propably you could use the mousedown and mouseup event https://api.jquery.com/mousedown/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you need to use the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events. On mouse down you can use a `setInterval()` to repeatedly move the element in the required direction. You can also (optionally) use a `setTimeout()` to add a delay before the repeated action starts to stop accidental duplicate movements. In the `mouseup` you simply need to then clear those timers.

Also note that you can genericise the code by using a `data` attribute to store the direction in which the relevant button should move the selected option.

Try this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.item', function() {
  $('.marked').removeClass('marked');
  $(this).addClass('marked');
});

var mouseTimer, mouseInterval;
$('.mpbtn').on({
    mousedown: function() {
        var dir = parseInt($(this).data('dir'), 10);
        move(dir);
        mouseTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            mouseInterval = setInterval(function() {
                move(dir)
            }, 100);
        }, 250);
    },
    mouseup: function() {
        clearTimeout(mouseTimer);
        clearInterval(mouseInterval);
    }
});

function move(dir) {
    if (dir < 0 && $('.marked').index() == 0)
        return;

    var i = $('.marked').index() + dir;
    $('.marked')[dir < 0 ? 'insertBefore' : 'insertAfter']($('.item').eq(i));
}

// only to populate demo:
var html = '';
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  html += '<div class="item">' + i + '</div>';
}
$('#itemwrap').html(html).find('div:first').addClass('marked');
```

```css
.marked {
  background: red;
}
.item {
  cursor: pointer
}
.mpbtn {
  background: teal;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='itemwrap'></div><br><br>

<div class='mpbtn' id='mpup' data-dir="-1">UP</div><br>
<div class='mpbtn' id='mpdown' data-dir="1">DOWN</div>
```

[**Working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/kkrf50we/2/)

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Note my last update with a couple of tweaks to change timings and structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.mpbtn').on('mousedown', function() {
   setInterval(function() {   
       console.log('hold');
       /* put code here */
   }, 1000);
   /* 1000 ms = 1 sec */
}).on('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
   console.log('unclick');
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Please test your code before placing it as answer.